# Unable to build Lagom sample project

Tags: maven-3, lagom

I have setup sample java based lagom project from **Tech Hub Project Starter.**

I try to run the project as per given command at lagom site

```
mvn lagom:runAll
```

Gets this below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lightbend.lagom:lagom-maven-plugin:1.4.5-M1:runAll (default-cli) on project MyProject: Execution default-cli of goal com.lightbend.lagom:lagom-maven-plugin:1.4.5-M1:runAll failed: Unable to load the mojo 'runAll' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'com.lightbend.lagom:lagom-maven-plugin:1.4.5-M1': java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR]   roleHint: com.lightbend.lagom:lagom-maven-plugin:1.4.5-M1:runAll
```

Maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T01:19:05+05:30)

Java version: 1.8.0_102, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Help me to solve the build issue.

Comment: Can  you provide the full output from running `mvn -e lagom:runAll`?

Comment: Yes, I use this command mvn lagom:runAll.

Comment: Right... I'm asking you to use `mvn -e lagom:runAll` instead, and then paste everything it outputs. This will print out more detail about the error.